# Error in jquery response error

Tags: controller, jquery, html

I have the following piece of code

```
var sContactId = jQuery("[id$=contactId]").attr("value"); 

jQuery("#responseErrors").html("Check"+sContactId);
```

Now, it is not printing the value of sContactId. I am not sure where am I going wrong.

Comment: Please check in the console whether you are receiving any jquery error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
jQuery("#responseErrors").html("Check"+jQuery("[id$=contactId]").val());
```

It will work for you.